# Add ID to geojson feature on load in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am loading a geojson layer into a leaflet map.  I want to set the svg element's ID according to an attribute stored in the geojson.

I assume I use the onEachFeature function, but I can't see how to set the ID of the feature as it parses.

How do I assign the ID of the element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible but not by using the `onEachFeature` method of `L.GeoJSON`. This because of the following:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // At this point 'layer._path' exists in the layer object
        // but it will return as 'undefined' so this is of no use
        // So the following doesn't work:
        layer._path.id = 'feature-' + feature.properties.id
    }
});
```

However if you use the `eachLayer` method from `L.GeoJSON`, `layer._path` will return the actual SVG path element, however it will do this only after the GeoJSON layer is added to the map. If you do this before adding the layer to the map `layer._path` will still return as `undefined`. So try this:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);

geoJsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer._path.id = 'feature-' + layer.feature.properties.id;
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7IPHrO?p=preview

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm.  A quick note for others, on my implementation I had to check that the variable was defined before assigning as I was getting some extra features being passed through that did not have a path.  Thanks!

Comment: So I found out that the extra features were multi-polygons and I was skipping over them with the above solution.  Instead you need to iterate over each layer of the multi-polygon feature.  A use of a class is then more appropriate than an id as posed by my original question. `if(typeof layer._path != 'undefined'){
            layer._path.id = layer.feature.properties.id;
        } else {
            layer.eachLayer(function (layer2){
                layer2._path.id = layer.feature.properties.id;
            });
        }`